# Can't create class var dynamically

Tags: php

I want add class vars at runtime of php script but seems something doing wrong and that code doesn't work as expected.

```
class Payment_gateway_2checkout extends CI_Driver {
var $table = '2checkout';

public function __construct()
{

    ci()->load->config('payment');

    $config = ci()->config->item('2checkout');
    print_r($config);
    foreach ($config as $k => $v)
    {
        echo "$k - $v<br>";
        $this->{$k} = $v;
    }
    echo "SID = '$this->sid'";

    var_export($this);
    exit;       
}
```

Here is output

```
Array ( [sid] => 901310601 [secure_key] => 684 [test] => 1 ) 
sid - 901310601
secure_key - 684
test - 1
SID = ''
Payment_gateway_2checkout::__set_state(array(
   'table' => '2checkout ',
   'parent' => NULL,
   'methods' => 
  array (
  ),
   'properties' => 
  array (
  ),
))
```

`$this->sid` is empty but I suppose to see `901310601`

**UPDATE**
here is dump of `this`

```
Payment_gateway_2checkout::__set_state(array(
   'table' => '2checkout ',
   'parent' => NULL,
   'methods' => 
  array (
  ),
   'properties' => 
  array (
  ),
))
```

Comment: Is this code in a class method?

Comment: @Rizier123 is in __construct

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump()` on your entire class object?

Comment: @Zander Rootman see my update, I have added the dump

Comment: `$this` might fall into a different context than `$var = new Object();`.. Well not might, it does. `$this` at any given time during construction refers to the current state of the object. And not the completed state. I'll post a plausible answer in a minute or so. Just doing some digging.

Comment: The issue is most likely with your `__set()` method in the parent class. Check that it might not be overwritten. Also, check that the properties you're trying to assign values to, are not defined by your parent class as finals or static, something along that line. But I can assure you there's nothing wrong with how you're trying to dynamically assign properties in your child class constructor.